# CheckboxTable from material UI is not updating on props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am building an admin system and I want to list the users in a table - and be able to perform bulk commands -- like bulk delete, bulk update flags - pagination.

```
<CheckboxTable
  header={this.getUserTableData().header}
  rows={this.getUserTableData().rows}
  handleAction={this.handleAction}
  otherActions={this.getUserTableData().otherActions}
  rowsPerPage={7}
/>
```

[image]

I've placed the codebase into a sandbox but I can't seem to fix the sandbox error - useLocation().

The issue I'm having is that the table doesn't update when the commands are sent back to the parent and the parent component has made the changes and returns new table data back down. I am unsure how to fix the issue as I need to push the row information into a state on the child to handle pagination changes inside the child itself.

--- current sandbox (broken in setup)
https://codesandbox.io/s/codepen-with-react-forked-uv5l0e?file=/src/components/CheckboxTable/CheckboxTable.js:3848-3888

I want to send to the component an object from the parent that gives the head,row and action details so various callbacks and selectedids can come back to the parent to perform those operations.

```
   getUserTableData() {

    console.log("this.state.users", this.state.users.people);

    let rows = [];

    for (let i=0; i < this.state.users.people.length; ++i) {
      console.log("this.state.users.people[i]", this.state.users.people[i]);
  
      let obj = {
        "id": this.state.users.people[i].id,
        "name": <NavLink to={"/users/"+this.state.users.people[i].id} activeClassName="selected">{this.state.users.people[i].name}</NavLink>,
        "isTrial": this.state.users.people[i].isTrial,
        "isVIP": this.state.users.people[i].isVIP,
        "createdAt": moment(this.state.users.people[i].createdAt).format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss'),
      }

      rows.push(obj);
    }


    let table = {
      header: [
        "id",
        "name",
        "isTrial",
        "isVIP",
        "createdAt",
      ],
      rows: rows,
      otherActions: [
        //{
        //  "label" : "Filter",
        //  "action": "filter",
        //  "icon" : <FilterListIcon />
        //},
        {
          "label" : "Trial",
          "action": "trial",
          "icon" : <FreeBreakfastIcon />
        },
        {
          "label" : "VIP",
          "action": "vip",
          "icon" : <LabelImportantIcon />
        },
        {
          "label" : "Delete",
          "action": "delete",
          "icon" : <DeleteIcon />
        }      
      ]
    }

    return table
  }
```

source work - material ui sorting/selecting table

sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/vk7cqh?file=/demo.js

this is based on the material ui table - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#sorting-amp-selecting - but my component takes a table object from the parent -- I tried to recreate this https://codesandbox.io/s/vk7cqh?file=/demo.js without hardcoding the data inside the component and running createData procedurally.

```
this.state = {
  "users": {
    "people" : [
      {
        "id": "1234",
        "name": "Joel Kip",
        "isTrial": false,
        "isVIP" : true,
        "createdAt": "2023-03-25 16:00:00"
      },
      {
        "id": "1236",
        "name": "Billy Kip",
        "isTrial": false,
        "isVIP" : false,
        "createdAt": "2023-03-25 16:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It would be good to get the functionality working if you delete a user for example or set another action like isTrial to true -- get the padding dense and re-instate sorting. Also I had to expose the ID to get the checkbox selection to work - I am unsure as to how to hide this visually from the current implementation

So when an admin clicks on a bulk icon - it triggers an action like this -- in the parent.

```
  handleAction(action, selectedItems) {
    console.log("data",action,selectedItems)

    if(action === "delete"){
      this.deleteUsers(selectedItems[0]);
    }
  }

  deleteUsers(id){

    let that = this;
    this.props.deleteUsers(id, "getToken()", function(resp) {
      if(resp){
        that.fetchUsers(); // get new updated data -- but this is where the new data props are not affecting the table
      }
    });

  }
```

[image]

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/codepen-with-react-forked-wm3oh9

Answer (score 0):

"If the CheckboxTable component from Material UI is not updating when its props change, there are a few things you can check.

First, make sure that the props being passed to the CheckboxTable component are actually changing. You can use console.log statements to check the values of the props before and after the change.

Second, check if the parent component is properly re-rendering when the props change. If the parent component is not re-rendering, then the CheckboxTable component will not receive the updated props. You can try updating the parent component's logic to trigger a re-render when the props change.

Third, check if the CheckboxTable component is using the props in a way that would require it to update. For example, if the component is only rendering the props once, it will not update even if the props change. You can try using the key prop on the CheckboxTable component to force it to re-render when the props change.

Finally, check if there are any errors or warnings in the console that may be preventing the CheckboxTable component from updating. This can include errors related to the props being passed or warnings about deprecated methods or functions.

If none of these solutions work, you may need to inspect the component's code to see if there are any state or derived values that are not being properly updated when the props change. You can also check the Material UI documentation or community forums for further guidance."

Comment: In the material ui checkboxtable example -- they have hard coded the data and it sits inside that component -- all I've tried to do is take out the data at the parent level and get rid of the hard coding aspect --- it displayed the data ok -- but if the table like I am trying to use it for - modifies itself -- like an admin listing users and performing bulk actions - that's where the issue is happening - its not updating itself from the changes being made from it -- and I think the states is there to solve pagination internally - but this could be having an impact